# Loop that creates labels that can open a new form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

hey everyone can someone help me with some codes in vb.net

i created a loop that can generate labels with my OleDbDataReader 
now i was wondering if i can make those labels open new form 
and can i use the data in this label in my new form like the label text created ! 
here is my code :

```
        Dim cnn As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbDataAdapter(cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    cmd.Fill(dt)
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
    reader = cnn.ExecuteReader()

    Dim number As Integer = 0
    Dim location As Integer = 0
    While reader.Read()

        Dim sensibleFont As New Font("Segoe UI", 15)

        Dim lb As New Label()
        lb.Name = "labb" + number.ToString
        lb.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(350, 40)
        lb.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(50, 15 + location)
        lb.Text = dt.Rows(number)(0).ToString()
        lb.ForeColor = Color.Black
        lb.Font = sensibleFont
        GroupBox1.Controls.Add(lb)

        Dim lb2 As New Label()
        lb2.Name = "labs" + number.ToString
        lb2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(280, 40)
        lb2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 5 + location)
        lb2.Text = dt.Rows(number)(2).ToString()
        lb2.ForeColor = Color.Black
        lb2.Font = sensibleFont
        GroupBox2.Controls.Add(lb2)

        location += 40
        number += 1
    End While

    con.Close()
```

Comment: Your reader looks unnecessary since you fill the DataTable and then use information from the DataTable in the loop, not from the reader. Just loop through the rows of the DataTable.  Create a click method in your code: `Private Sub LabelClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)` and then use `AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf LabelClicked` to wire your new label to the click event.  It's what the designer is doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub that does what you want.

```
Private Sub OpenForm()
    Dim myForm As New MyForm()
    myForm.Show()
End Sub
```

During label creation, add a click event that uses this sub as it's handler

```
AddHandler lb.Click, AddressOf OpenForm
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the answer by A Friend, you can add a handler to a label's click event. Extending that to use the correct signature for the handler, you can get the object which raised the event and so use its properties, such as the `.Text` property:

```
Sub Label_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lbl = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    Dim frm2 = New OtherForm(lbl.Text)
    frm2.Show()

End Sub
```

To go with it, you will need a constructor (the `Sub New`) in the other form (which I named "OtherForm") like this:

```
Public Class OtherForm

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

    End Sub

    Sub New(info As String)
        InitializeComponent()

        Label1.Text = info

    End Sub

End Class
```

Where `Label1` is just a label I put on `OtherForm` for testing purposes.

You might find the `.Tag` property of a control better for passing data as it can be any Object, e.g. an instance of a class.

I notice that you are reading the database twice: once to fill the datatable and then again as a count of the rows in the datatable, which is a bit wasteful. Also, you should dispose of a font when you have finished with it: the Using construct will take care of that for you, similarly for a connection to a database. Like this:

```
Sub PopulateGroupBox()
    Dim connStr = "CONNECTION STRING HERE"
    Dim query = "SQL QUERY HERE"

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
        Dim cnn As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbDataAdapter(cnn)
        cmd.Fill(dt)
    End Using

    Dim location As Integer = 0

    Using sensibleFont As New Font("Segoe UI", 15)

        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim lb1 As New Label()
            lb1.Name = "labb" & i.ToString()
            lb1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(350, 40)
            lb1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(50, 15 + location)
            lb1.Text = dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
            lb1.ForeColor = Color.Black
            lb1.Font = sensibleFont
            AddHandler lb1.Click, AddressOf Label_Click
            GroupBox1.Controls.Add(lb1)

            Dim lb2 As New Label()
            lb2.Name = "labs" & i.ToString()
            lb2.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(280, 40)
            lb2.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10, 5 + location)
            lb2.Text = dt.Rows(i)(2).ToString()
            lb2.ForeColor = Color.Black
            lb2.Font = sensibleFont
            AddHandler lb2.Click, AddressOf Label_Click
            GroupBox2.Controls.Add(lb2)

            location += 40

        Next

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: i didn't get it how to pass the lb1,text to the other form
can u explain it more ?

Comment: The `Sub New(info As String)` of OtherForm takes a parameter. `Dim frm2 = New OtherForm(lbl.Text)` passes that parameter to it.